# Can I set a disc name when burning a DVD via terminal?

Tags: command-line, iso, dvd

In terminal, can I burn data files to DVD with a disc name that I supply without creating a ISO?

Comment: can you post the command you're using to burn?

Comment: i'm using sudo wodim  dev=/dev/sr0 -v -data /path/to/data/

Comment: wodim burns images or image streams to medium. The disc name is already encoded in the image. Natural image producer program for wodim is genisoimage.

Comment: wodim is mainly for CD media. Not very good with DVD. Better are: growisofs, cdrecord, xorriso, cdrskin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by "without creating a ISO" that no intermediate image file
shall be stored on hard disk:

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -volid "MY_DISC_NAME" -map /hard/disk/file_path /iso/file_path -map /another/hd/path /another/iso_path
```

If the DVD shall not get an ISO 9660 filesystem, then you need a producer
of your desired filesystem which puts out its result on standard output.
This output stream can then be piped into a burn program like growisofs
or xorriso. Like

```
producer_program options ... | xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -
```

The disk name has to be encoded by the producer program into the output
stream.

Comment: Thanks. That's i meant, but i can't find anything about xorriso and producer_program in my system - ubuntu desktop 16.04.

Comment: @HữuTuấnAnh, [xorriso](https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/)

Comment: Ubuntu binary package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xorriso (Thanks to Sirajus Salekin for pointing to its home page as standalone program.) Candidates for the role of producer_program would be genisoimage or tar.